# Which object I can pass into JSON in asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, listbox

I have created to list box. Left listbox contains List Items and the right list box nothing have at server side.

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <asp:ListBox ID="lstLeft" class="form-control" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Height="220px">
        <asp:ListItem Value="transactions.storeid as StoreID">StoreID</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="YEAR(transactions.Time) Year">Year</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="MONTH(transactions.Time) Month">Month</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="transactionsEntry.TransactionNumber">TransactionNumber</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="transactionsEntry.Quantity">Quantity</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="items.ItemLookupCode">ItemLookupCode</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="CONVERT(varchar, CAST(transactionsEntry.Price AS money), 1)*transactionsEntry.Quantity ExtendedPrice">ExtendedPrice</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="departments.Name as DepartmentName">DepartmentName</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="categories.Name as CategoryName">CategoryName</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="items.SubDescription1">SubDescription1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="suppliers.SupplierName">SupplierName</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="suppliers.Code">Code</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:ListBox>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <input type="button" id="left" value="<<" />
        <input type="button" id="right" value=">>" />
    </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
        <asp:ListBox ID="lstRight" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="100%" Height="220"></asp:ListBox>
    </div>
 </div>
```

At runtime I am moving a list items from left list box to right list box by clicking button through Jquery.

```
$(function () {

            $("#left").bind("click", function () {
                var options = $("[id*=lstRight] option:selected");
                for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    var opt = $(options[i]).clone();
                    $(options[i]).remove();
                    $("[id*=lstLeft]").append(opt);
                }
            });
            $("#right").bind("click", function () {
                var options = $("[id*=lstLeft] option:selected");

                for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                    var opt = $(options[i]).clone();

                    $(options[i]).remove();
                    $("[id*=lstRight]").append(opt);
                }

            });
```

Now I want to add listbox items which is moved in Right ListBox using JSON. 
So I want to make one map variable in jquery and pass that variable on JSON and then Add those values in Right listbox at server side.

Here what i tried to get all text and values and put it in one variable. But i Don't understand how it's working and which variable i should pass in json.

```
var options = $('#lstRight option');
var values = $.map(options, function (option) {
    alert("Text = " + option.text + " Value = " + option.value);
    //alert("Values =" + values);
});
```

> When I try this one `alert("Values =" + values);` I am getting undefined. So which variable I should pass in JSON

thanks

Comment: @Div still same out `undefined`. `var options = $('#lstRight option');
                    var values = $.map(options, function (option) {
                        //alert("Text = " + option.text + " Value = " + option.value);
                        alert("Values =" + JSON.stringify(values));
                    });`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to get the value and text of Listbox.

```
//Define javascript array

var arr = new Array;

$("#lstRight > option").each(function () {
       arr.push({ "Text" : $(this).text() , "Value" : $(this).val() });
});

//convert this array into json using JSON.stringify function

JSON.stringify(arr);
```

also check for the client side id of the asp.net Listbox control when rendered in browser.

Comment: I think you don't understand my question. I already got the values and text. I want to store all the text and values in one array like (keys,values). and then I want to pass that array to json and add those keys and values in right listbox items at server side. Understand?